# Use "originalWidth:int" and "originalHeight:int" several times on different objects

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, height, width, movieclip

**I'm attempting to** create a "template" in which I´ll **replace 4 images**, each one with different sizes on different frames of 4 different buttons.

**But each time I replace them the size,nor it's position nor it´s aspect ratio shouldn't be changed.**

For that puropose I found this code:

```
var originalWidth:int = button1.width / button1.scaleX;
var originalHeight:int = button1.height / button1.scaleY;
```

which was useful for only one button.But when I do this:

```
var originalWidth:int = button1.width / button1.scaleX;
var originalHeight:int = button1.height / button1.scaleY;

var originalWidth:int = button2.width / button2.scaleX;
var originalHeight:int = button2.height / button2.scaleY;

var originalWidth:int = button3.width / button3.scaleX;
var originalHeight:int = button3.height / button3.scaleY;

var originalWidth:int = button4.width / button4.scaleX;
var originalHeight:int = button4.height / button4.scaleY;
```

It triggers the following errors:

- main, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 37  1151: A conflict exists with definition originalWidth in namespace internal.
- main, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 38  1151: A conflict exists with definition originalHeight in namespace internal.
- main, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 40  1151: A conflict exists with
  definition originalWidth in namespace internal.
- main, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 41  1151: A conflict exists with
  definition originalHeight in namespace internal.
- main, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 43  1151: A conflict exists with
  definition originalWidth in namespace internal.
- main, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 44  1151: A conflict exists with
  definition originalHeight in namespace internal.
- ComponentShim (Compiled Clip), Line 1    5000: The class
  'fl.core.ComponentShim' must subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip' since
  it is linked to a library symbol of that type.
- ComponentShim (Compiled Clip), Line 1    5000: The class
  'fl.controls.UIScrollBar' must subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip'
  since it is linked to a library symbol of that type.

**PD:**
the solutions given only keps the original size of the first button but not the rest

Comment: Welcome to OOP. OOP allows you to declare as much as one field of a certain name within one context. You (as a human object) cannot have two properties named 'age' or 'height'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that you're trying to create variables named the same as variables you already created on this frame or object.

```
// Variables on an object must have unique names
var originalWidth0:int = button1.width / button1.scaleX;
var originalHeight0:int = button1.height / button1.scaleY;

var originalWidth1:int = button2.width / button2.scaleX;
var originalHeight1:int = button2.height / button2.scaleY;

// etc.
```

If you have a lot of buttons, consider storing the original button sizes in an array. This avoids having to create all the 'original size' variables manually:

```
// Instance name of first button should be button0, followed by button1 etc.
// This is because we are using an array — and arrays are zero-based (first index is 0).

var numberOfButtons = 4;
var originalButtonSizes = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++)
{
    var originalSize = new Object();
    var button = this["button" + i];
    originalSize.width = button.width / button.scaleX;
    originalSize.height = button.height / button.scaleY;
    originalButtonSizes[i] = originalSize;
}

// Get the first button's original size
trace(originalButtonSizes[0].width);
```